# How to iterate through a data structure--such as a LinkedList with Nodes--nondestructively?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I've been warned about being careful when iterating through a LinkedList implements with Nodes because you may be changing the original list. For example, if I pass in a Node head, and continuously call head.next, will it change what the original LinkedList is? If I set Node currNode = head, and then continuously call currNode.next, am I guaranteed that the original isn't changed? If not guaranteed, when would calling currNode.next not work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand currently you've no problem but you are just curios.

```
public class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;
}

public void print(){
   Node curr = this.head;
   while(curr != null){
      System.out.println(curr.data);
      curr = curr.next;
   }
}
```

If you’ve a class model as above and you’ve a variable called head.
If you want to iterate you just need to assign head to a new variable called curr and iterate using it. This way head still reference the root value.